# Make a square pattern in C++

Tags: c++

I have a task to make a half-square pattern, where the input must be an even number

Example 1

```
Enter row & column = 4
Output
WWOO
wWOO
OOWW
OOWW
```

Example 2

```
Enter row & column = 8
Output
WWWWOOOO
WWWWOOOO
WWWWOOOO
WWWWOOOO
OOOOWWWW
OOOOWWWW
OOOOWWWW
OOOOWWWW
```

here's my code so far,i have tried to show even number output, but i don't have any ide to show half square pattern

```
int main ()
{
    int size;
    cout<<"Square Pattern\n";
    cout<<"==============\n";
    cout<<"Input :";cin>>size;
    
    if(size%2!=0)
    {
        cout<<"Input must be even number !";
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        { 

            for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            {  
                if( ? )
                {
                    cout << "W";
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "O";
                }

            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try to describe it in words. Let's say I have painted a square but haven't filled out the fields, and I now point at a specific field. How would you determine whether it is W or O? Answer this in a full sentence first. And then try to translate it into a boolean expression.

Comment: How about two loops, each over `size / 2` characters?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude With this approach it might eventually be two loops, each over `size/2` lines, and in each of them another two loops, each over `size/2` characters.

Answer (score 1):

You need to output `'W'` if both the number of the row **and** the number of the character in the row are less than `size/2` **or** both are greater than or equal to `size/2`; and `'O'` otherwise.

```
    for(int row = 0; row < size; row++)
    {
        for(int column = 0; column < size; column++)
            if( (row < size/2) == (column < size/2) )
                cout << "W";
            else
                cout << "O";

        cout << endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will return the pattern you want :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int size;
    cout<<"Square Pattern\n";
    cout<<"==============\n";
    cout<<"Input :";cin>>size;
    
    if(size%2!=0)
    {
        cout<<"Input must be even number !";
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < size/2; i++)
        { 

            for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            {  
                if( j<size/2 )
                {
                    cout << "W";
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "O";
                }

            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        for(int i = size/2; i < size; i++)
        { 

            for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            {  
                if( j<size/2 )
                {
                    cout << "O";
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "W";
                }

            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using two loops. Keeping two characters c1 and c2. In the first half, c1 is set to 'W' and c2 is set to 'O'. Interchanging the contents of the variables after the first half of the total iterations. Try this :

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    int size;
    cout<<"Square Pattern\n";
    cout<<"==============\n";
    cout<<"Input :";cin>>size;
    char c1,c2;
    if(size%2!=0)
    {
        cout<<"Input must be even number !";
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            if((i+1)<=size/2)
            {
                c1 = 'W'; c2 = 'O';
            }
            else
            {
                c1 = 'O'; c2 = 'W';
            }
            for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            {  
                if((j+1)<=size/2)
                {
                    cout << c1;
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << c2;
                }
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified your snippet to which gives the required result:

```
int main ()
{
    int size;
    cout<<"Square Pattern\n";
    cout<<"==============\n";
    cout<<"Input :";cin>>size;
    
    if(size%2!=0)
    {
        cout<<"Input must be even number !";
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        { 

            for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            {  
                //Actual different part from your code
                /* There will be 2 nested if condition because your pattern is 
                dependent on both "i" and "j" */ 
                if(i<size/2){
                    if( j<size/2)
                    {
                        cout << "W";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cout << "O";
                    }
                }else{
                    if( j<size/2)
                    {
                        cout << "O";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cout << "W";
                    }
                }
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}
```